# If-elif-else code after another If-elif-else code isn't being run

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a "Sleep Monitoring" software that checks if one's eyes are open/closed. The conditions are as follows:

1. Program displays the results (e.g. eyes open/close) for the first frame, then displays notifications for the succeeding frames **only if there are changes in eye status**.
2. If eyes are opened, program sends a message "Client is Awake"; if not, the program does nothing unless the eyes have been closed for 10 seconds, in which case, the program sends message "Client is Sleeping".

The code for the tracking is as follows (to avoid confusion, please focus on the if-elif-else conditions only):

```
def eye_aspect_ratio(self, eye): #function to get eye aspect ratio
    
    a = dist.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])
    b = dist.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])

    c = dist.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])

    ear = (a + b) / (2.0 * c)

    return ear

def startstream2(self): #function for tracking software

    try:

        self.temp = ""
        self.result = ""

        counter = 0

        self.vs.start() #self.vs = VideoStream(src = 0)

        EYE_AR_THRESH = 0.35
        
        # initialize dlib's face detector (HOG-based) and then create
        # the facial landmark predictor

        print("[INFO] loading facial landmark predictor...")

        detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
        predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

        # grab the indexes of the facial landmarks for the left and
        # right eye, respectively
        (lStart, lEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["left_eye"]
        (rStart, rEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["right_eye"]

        while not self.flag.is_set(): #self.flag = Event()

            frame = self.vs.read()

            if frame.size == 0: #check if frame is null

                print ("No Face Detected")

                return

            else:

                frame = imutils.resize(frame, width = 1080 )
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                # detect faces in the grayscale frame
                rects = detector(gray, 0)

                # loop over the face detections
                for rect in rects:
                    # determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
                    # convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy
                    # array
                    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
                    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

                    # extract the left and right eye coordinates, then use the
                    # coordinates to compute the eye aspect ratio for both eyes
                    leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
                    rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]

                    leftEAR = self.eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
                    rightEAR = self.eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)

                    # average the eye aspect ratio together for both eyes
                    ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR)

                    # compute the convex hull for the left and right eye, then
                    # visualize each of the eyes
                    leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)
                    rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)
                    cv2.drawContours(frame, [leftEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
                    cv2.drawContours(frame, [rightEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

                    if self.result == "" or self.result.isspace(): #check if self.result value is null; if yes that means this is the first frame

                        # check to see if the eye aspect ratio is below the blink threshold
                        
                        if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH: #means eyes are closed

                            self.result = "CLOSED:"

                            print ("First frame, eyes are closed")
                        
                        elif ear > EYE_AR_THRESH:
                            
                            print ("First frame, Eyes open")

                            self.result = "AWAKE:"

                        else:

                            continue

                    else:

                        if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:

                            self.temp = "CLOSED:"

                        elif ear > EYE_AR_THRESH:

                            self.temp = "AWAKE:"

                        else: 

                            continue

                        print ("TEMP VALUE IS: " + self.temp) #for checking

                        if self.temp != self.result and self.temp == "AWAKE:": #if current frame and previous frame are not the same, and current frame == "AWAKE:", this means in the previous frame eyes were closed and the client has just opened their eyes
           
                            print ("SELF.RESULT BEFORE: " + self.result) #for checking

                            self.result = self.temp #value of current frame becomes value of previous frame

                            print ("SELF.RESULT AFTER: " + self.result) #for checking
                            print ("Client is Awake")
                            counter = 0

                        elif self.temp == self.result and self.temp == "CLOSED:": #if current frame has the same value as the previous frame, and current frame == CLOSED:, that means the client has been closing their eyes consecutively

                            if counter != 10:

                                time.sleep(1) #1 frame = 1 second

                                counter += 1

                                print ("SELF.RESULT BEFORE: " + self.result) #for checking

                                self.result = self.temp #value of current frame becomes value of previous frame

                                print ("SELF.RESULT AFTER: " + self.result)

                                print ("Counter added " + str(counter))

                            else:

                                print ("Client is Sleeping")

                                counter = 0

                                print ("COUNTER = 0") #for checking

                                print ("SELF.RESULT BEFORE: " + self.result) #for checking

                                self.result = self.temp #value of current frame becomes value of previous frame

                                print ("SELF.RESULT AFTER: " + self.result) #for checking

                        else:

                            continue

        else:

            print ("Inside destroy")

            self.vs.stop()

            self.result = ""

            self.temp = ""

            return

    except Exception as e:

            print ("No Face Detected")

            print (traceback.format_exc())
```

The problem comes when there are changes in the eye status. Assuming the client has closed their eyes for 2 seconds, then opens them, the output should be as follows:

**EXPECTATION**

```
[INFO] loading facial landmark predictor...
First frame, eyes are closed
TEMP VALUE IS: CLOSED:
SELF.RESULT BEFORE: CLOSED:
SELF.RESULT AFTER: CLOSED:
Counter added 1
TEMP VALUE IS: AWAKE:
SELF.RESULT BEFORE: CLOSED:
SELF.RESULT AFTER: AWAKE:
Client is Awake
```

**REALITY**

```
[INFO] loading facial landmark predictor...
First frame, eyes are closed
TEMP VALUE IS: CLOSED:
TEMP VALUE IS: AWAKE:
```

For some reason, the if-elif-else statements after the line `print ("TEMP VALUE IS: " + self.temp)` isn't being run. I've tried commenting out the aforementioned line, reloading the VS Code editor, checked for missing indentations, and put the not running if-elif-else statements in a different function and did

```
print ("TEMP VALUE IS: " + self.temp)
self.runfunction()
```

but it didn't work as well. Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: I don't really know what your code is doing, but is there any chance you always end up in the "else: continue" section without noticing?

Comment: Don't know if intended, but when `ear == EYE_AR_THRESH`, you will `continue` without setting `self.temp`

Comment: I would print print ("Result VALUE IS: " + self.result) on the line after print ("TEMP VALUE IS: " + self.temp). It's hard to tell for sure, but I wonder if self.result is never set, so none of the if-elif conditional evaluate to True.

Comment: @freqnseverity there is `self.result = "CLOSED:"` on the line above `print ("First frame, eyes are closed")` so I think it is set

Comment: @Rafalon Oh shit, you're right. I'll try to look into it, thanks.